# Arbitrary axis billboard matrix

Tags: opengl-es, camera, rotation

First, my requirement is calculating the billboard matrix in vertex shader.

The billboard's position doesn't change, but the direction is facing to the camera.

Then, the camera is real-time rotation around any axis.

My codes are:

```
mat4 BillboardMatrix( vec3 pos)
{
    vec3 forward = normalize(pos - worldCameraPos);

    vec3 side = cross( forward, worldCameraUp);


   mat4 result;
   result[0] = vec4( side, 0.0 );
   result[1] = vec4( worldCameraUp,0.0);
   result[2] = vec4( forward.x, 0.0, forward.z , 0.0 );
   result[3] = vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
   return result;
}
```

The question:

When the camera is rotating around X axis or Y axis, the effect is right.When the camera is rotating around Z axis, the billboard is also rotating, I don't want this Z rotation.

Answer (score 0):

You may force the base vectors to identity by doing:

```
result[0] = vec4(1.0, .0, .0, .0);
result[1] = vec4(.0, 1.0, .0, .0);
result[2] = vec4(.0, .0, 1.0, .0);
```

This will discard the scale though so if you need it then you need to find the length of base vectors first and multiply the identity with them:

```
mat4 originalMatrix; // The matrix without billboarding

mat4 result;
result[0] = vec4(length(originalMatrix[0].xyz), .0, .0, .0);
result[1] = vec4(.0, length(originalMatrix[1].xyz), .0, .0);
result[2] = vec4(.0, .0, length(originalMatrix[2].xyz), .0);
result[3] = originalMatrix[3];
```

At least I hope you use the matrix this way.

- This means you will preserve the position which is stored in `originalMatrix[3]`.
- You will discard rotations which are the top left 3x3 part of your matrix so the result is as if you were drawing in 2d.
- You will preserve any scaling of the object since the base vectors are multiplied with the length of original base vectors. Base vectors are the top left 3x3 part as `x = originalMatrix[0].xyz`, `y = originalMatrix[1].xyz`, `z = originalMatrix[2].xyz`.
- You will discard all scaling per dimension. These are defined by `w` components next to base vectors. Mostly `Z` is used to change `X` and `Y` depending on the distance of the object (frustum). To preserve those you need to change to:

Preserving projection scale:

```
mat4 originalMatrix; // The matrix without billboarding

mat4 result;
result[0] = vec4(length(originalMatrix[0].xyz), .0, .0, originalMatrix[0].w);
result[1] = vec4(.0, length(originalMatrix[1].xyz), .0, originalMatrix[1].w);
result[2] = vec4(.0, .0, length(originalMatrix[2].xyz), originalMatrix[2].w);
result[3] = originalMatrix[3];
```

Comment: Anyway i must thank you, thank you very much.I found a sample method that I used vec3 up = vec3(0.0,1.0,0.0) to replace worldCameraUp,and this effect was right!!